# remove element from vector of vectors

Tags: java

I try to remove an element from vector of verctors in Java, and set this vector to the correct location.

So I try this, and of course it didn't work because line (2) return Integer:

**Definition:**

```java
Vector<Vector<Integer>> current_domain;

Vector<Integer> t = current_domain.get(k).remove(0);
current_domain.set(k, t);
```

Comment: "of course it didn't work" - so, what's your questions?

Comment: It would help a little if you shared what are you actually trying to achieve or what do you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>> current_domain;
```

For the above Vector: -

```
current_domain.get(k)
```

returns a `Vector<Integer>`. And when you use `remove(0)` on it, you will get an `integer`, which you cannot assign to a `Vector`.

Also when you use: -

```
current_domain.get(k).remove(0);
```

It will modify your `vector` automatically. So you don't need to set it again.

```
    Vector<Vector<Integer>> current_domain = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();

    Vector<Integer> vect = new Vector<Integer>();
    vect.add(4);
    vect.add(5);

    current_domain.add(vect);
    current_domain.get(0).remove(0);

    System.out.println(current_domain);
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
[[5]]
```

So, you can see that `Vector` is modified.

---

As a side note, I would suggest to use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector<Integer> t = current_domain.get(k).remove(0);

current_domain.get(k)-->returns a Vector<Integer>

Vector<Integer>.remove(0)---> returns an Integer
```

try :

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>> current_domain=null;
Vector<Integer> t = current_domain.get(0);
t.remove(0);
```

Comment: Actually, `t.remove(0)` will automatically modify the original Vector. So you don't need to set it again. So, you can remove the last line. You do understand that `t` reference points to same `Vector` right?

Comment: @RohitJain oops, its actually a copy paste thingy .. :P i have edited it now :)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYle.. Ah! Happens. And there you go, a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to think through logically what is being returned at each stage. Split things up to help you, and give variables proper, helpful names:

```
Vector<Integer> subVector = current_domain.get(k);
Integer intVal = subVector.remove(0);
//... now, what do you actually want to do with the integer?
```

Incidentally, you're using a very very odd data structure that is likely to be inefficient for  whatever you're doing with it (though the purpose of your endeavours is also not very clear).

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps trying to do:

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>> current_domain;

Vector<Integer> t = current_domain.remove(k);
// do something to t
current_domain.set(k, t);
```

? Remove returns the element, so you want to call it from the collection containing the element.